# How to solve the Integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty [\tanh(\frac{x+a/2}{b})-\tanh(\frac{x-a/2}{b})]e^{ikx} dx$?

Tags: integration

How to do the integral

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty [\tanh(\frac{x+a/2}{b})-\tanh(\frac{x-a/2}{b})]e^{ikx} dx$$

I had deal with this problem for whole day long......

I tried to turn the $\tanh$ into $\exp$ form.......

However, I get...

$$2(e^{a/b}-e^{-a/b}) \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{e^{2x/b}+e^{2a/b}+e^{-a/b}+e^{-2x/b}}dx$$

It seems that I just make things worse...........

Comment: Maybe differentiate wrt to $a $. Just a thought to try...

Comment: Also, perhaps Fourier transform or some integral transform method?

Comment: I put it into the Maple and no answer! :/ It might be a hard one! :)

Comment: Ya....... Really need help><

Comment: Let's wait til someone come up with some idea! If no answer appeared, I can put some bounty on it after two days to attract more attentions. :)

Comment: where did you encounter such an integral? :)

Comment: When I try to transfer a wave function $\psi(x)$ into $\phi(p)$ ........
$$\psi(x) =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \hbar}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty [\tanh(\frac{x+a/2}{b})-\tanh(\frac{x-a/2}{b})]e^{ikx} dx$$

Comment: Crossposted to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/217938/2451

Comment: Hmmm, splitting the integrations and substitute $y_{\pm}\frac{x\pm a/2}{b}$ one ends  with the difference ofintegrals of the form $ e^{\mp ia k/2}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\tanh(y_{\pm})e^{ i k  b y_{\pm}}dy_{\pm}$

which are just Fouriertransforms of $\tanh$ times constants. This  is known stuff

Comment: btw. your second integral could be done by contour integration

Comment: @tired: Can you write it as answer? :)

Comment: i'm too busy today, but u can even solve it even by elementary methods using $e^{2x/b}=z$

Answer (score 1):

If we take the logarithmic derivative of the Weierstrass product for the $\cosh$ function we get:

$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2+x^2} = \frac{\pi}{4x}\,\tanh\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right) \tag{1}$$
hence, in order to compute our integral, it is enough to compute (I am assuming $a,b,k\geq 0$):
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{8b(a+2x)}{b^2\pi^2(2n+1)^2+(a+2x)^2}\,e^{ikx}\,dx\\=\sum_{n\geq 0}e^{-iak/2}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{16bx}{b^2\pi^2(2n+1)^2+4x^2}e^{ikx}\,dx \\ = \sum_{n\geq 0}e^{-iak/2}\cdot 2\pi i b\cdot \exp\left(-\frac{\pi b (2n+1)k}{2}\right)\\=2\pi i b \cdot \frac{\exp\left(\frac{b\pi k-iak}{2}\right)}{e^{b\pi k}-1}.\tag{2}$$

Comment: interesting that mathematica insists of hypergeometric functions , which is clearly not necessarz

Comment: Can you add some explanation and more computational steps! I cannot really follow what happened! :) What is Weierstrass product? Why the summation and integration is interchangeable (uniform continuity maybe) and also how did you evaluate the last series? :)

Comment: @H.R.: The Weierstrass product is the usual way for writing some entire functions as products, look for it on Wikipedia. The integral/series exchange is allowed by the dominated convergence theorem and the last series is just a geometric series. The middle integral is evaluated through the residue theorem.